# PHP function not echoing variables

Tags: php, function, variables, echo

I have the following line in a file named config.php:

```
$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"] = "yes";
```

Then a file named funcs.php which includes config.php, with the following lines.

```
echo $objects["settings"]["template"]["value"];
function testfunction() {
    echo "<br />function output: ".$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"];
}
```

I then have index.php which includes funcs.php, as follows.

```
require_once("funcs.php");
testfunction();
```

How come the output from the function doesn't read the variables and they are empty?

```
yes
function output:
```

The output im expecting is:

```
yes
function output: yes
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I went with Yoda's answer as it was the most detailed answer regarding passing $objects as a parameter. Thanks to everyone else who answered!

Comment: variable scope issue: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Your `testfunction` doesn't have access to the `$objects` variable.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: tip, its better to use `return` inside the function and `echo` outside.

Comment: One solution would be to add the line `global $objects;` inside your function. Another woudl be to use the $GLOBALS array i.e. $GLOBALS['objects']["settings"]["template"]["value"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is not in function scope. You can achieve that by using `global` keyword. However doing it like this is bad practice and you should rather pass the value to function through function parameter.

Use of `global` (bad practice):

```
$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"] = "yes";

function testfunction() {
    global $objects;        
    echo "<br />function output: ".$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"];
}

testfunction();
```

Passing value through function parameter:

```
$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"] = "yes";

function testfunction($objects) {   
    echo "<br />function output: ".$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"];
}

testfunction($objects);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the most detailed answer of the answers suggesting to pass the object as a parameter which is what I have now done. Thanks to everyone that answered!

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass the object as parameter

```
function testfunction($objects) {
    echo "<br />function output: ".$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is outside the scope of the function. To make the variable available in the function, you have to pass is an argument into the function. You will also need to modify the function definition. See sample below

```
// function definition
function testFunction($variable) {
    echo $variable;
}

// call the function
$your_variable = "Some output";
testFunction($your_variable);
```

This should give you the expected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Using global can work, but it should only be used if you can't pass the variable through the function as it has some security risk...

```
$GLOBALS["settings"]["template"]["value"] = 'yes';
```

---

This works because it changes the scope of the variable to be global.

```
$GLOBALS["settings"]["template"]["value"] = 'yes';

function test(){

    echo $GLOBALS["settings"]["template"]["value"];

}

test();
```

The above prints out `yes`

Comment: posting a *don't do it like this* answer is not recommended.

Comment: @Dagon It's not a _don't do it like this answer_... it's a _do it like this, but a warning answer_.

Comment: @Arian I dont think it does, try `$GLOBALS['objects']["settings"]["template"]["value"]'

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited my answer, try the code, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Arian His question was using `$objects["settings"]["template"]["value"] = "yes";` your answer has changed the location of the tested value. Anyway you cannot frig the question to suit YOUR answer after the event.

Comment: @RiggsFolly All the other answers _frig_ the question to somehow have the variable `$objects`, to pass to `testfunction($objects);` when the OP originally stated that he only set it on the first php page.

Comment: @Arian No, the $objects array was declared in global scope. The function call `testfunction();` is in global scope. So passing `$objects` as a parameter to a function called from global scope passing an array which is also in global scope in normal/legal. And also conforms to the questioners situation.